# 48"NXR gas range no electric at all

Tags: appliances

I have a NXR 48" gas oven and range(NK4811) and I have no electric working at all, no lights, fans or anything. I checked my 110v power source and it is good, I am detecting power in the front but when I put my detector on the power cord it doesn't go off. I replaced the ignitor a few months ago but now it is totally dead. I can still use the gas burners but have to light them myself.

I called NXR to talk to a technician and can't get through to one. Seems odd since I was able to get through only a few months ago.

Comment: You might find a wiring diagram for it if you google.  Off hand I would think a fuse burned out or you have a loose or damaged connection in the stove wiring.

Comment: Does the receptacle work properly?

Comment: I fixed it. I found the ground wire had broke inside the connectors from the power cord. Very strange since it just sits there without any movement of any kind.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possibilities:

- Electrical fuse, or possibly circuit breaker

Most ovens and other large appliances have a replaceable fuse or a resettable circuit breaker (but more often a fuse because it shouldn't need replacement very often and a circuit breaker will cost an extra $5 to manufacture compared to a fuse and fuse holder). This would be indicated on the wiring diagram *somewhere*. The problem is often finding the wiring diagram. In the olden days, you would often find a printed wiring diagram hidden in the back or behind the control panel. But not always. Sometimes you can find it online, but the more unusual and/or high-end the brand, the less likely you can find it online as a regular user (as opposed to an authorized technician with special access).

There can actually be multiple fuses/breakers, though typically only one will cut off *everything*.

Assuming you find that and are able to reset or replace it, that may fix it - or it may trip again very quickly if the real problem still exists. Sometimes a part will go bad and blow a fuse but not actually damage anything else. That is very common with heating elements in electric ovens, and it could be a similar situation with the ignitor in a gas oven. But other times there is serious damage that either caused the overload or resulted from the overload.

- Thermal fuse.

This is an electrical fuse (it cuts all electric power) that is *not* triggered by a *current* overload but rather by a *thermal* overload - i.e., the oven got too hot. Typically these will be on the outside of the oven cavity and blow if either the oven gets much hotter than normal temperatures or if hot air from the oven gets to places that it shouldn't. It is a vital safety item, but is often hard to find/replace. I had one on top of my double wall oven, behind the control panel, which was easy. I had another *behind* the oven - that required building a contraption to be able to slide the oven out to work on it and was a two person job (barely - a third strong person would have been helpful!).

- Control Board Failure

This can be a cause (part of the board "burns up" and blows the fuse) or an effect (some other part - ignitor, etc. fails and causes an overcurrent situation that burns up part of the control board and *eventually* blows the fuse).

If it is a control board failure then it can get rather expensive (been there), unless it is somehow covered by warranty (fortunately been there some of the time).